# Como converter números em categorias no R

Tags: r

Em meu banco de dados, tenho uma Variável `TP_CorRaca` com os valores 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5.
Cada número corresponde a uma cor.

Exemplo:

0 - Branco

1 - preto

2 - pardo

...

Quero fazer essa correspondência para usar a função `lm()`.

Answer (score 6):

Esse é um caso em que os fatores são úteis. Basta você transformar sua variável em um fator.

Criando um vetor de exemplo:

```
set.seed(10)
exemplo_numero <- sample(0:5, 10, replace = TRUE)
```

Você pode usar a função `factor()` explicando o que é cada número:

```
exemplo_fator <- factor(exemplo_numero, 
                        levels = 0:5,
                        labels  = c("branco", "preto", "pardo", "amarelo", "indigena", "não declarado"))
exemplo_fator
[1] amarelo  preto    pardo    indigena branco   preto    preto    preto    amarelo  pardo   
Levels: branco preto pardo amarelo indigena não declarado
```

Answer (score 2):

Tem a função `recode` do `dplyr`. 
Usando o mesmo exemplo do @Carlos Cinelli

```
set.seed(10)
exemplo_numero <- sample(0:5, 10, replace = TRUE)

library(dplyr)
recode(exemplo_numero, `0` = "branco", `1` = "preto",`2`= "pardo", 
       `3` = "amarelo", `4` = "indigena", `5` = "não declarado")
#> [1] "amarelo"  "preto"    "pardo"    "indigena" "branco"   "preto"    "preto"    "preto"    "amarelo"  "pardo"
```

Note que os números precisam estar entre "`" o mesmo do acento crase.
O legal da função `recode` são os outros parâmetros como o `.default` e `.missing`.

```
x <- c(1:4, NA)
recode(x, `1` = "z", `2` = "y", .default = "D")
#> [1] "z" "y" "D" "D" NA 
recode(x, `1` = "z", `2` = "y", .default = "D", .missing = "M")
#> [1] "z" "y" "D" "D" "M"
```

O `.default` pode ser usado para preencher os valores não citados no código por algum valor. O `.missing` substitui valore `NA` por algum valor também.